# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Flux<String> to Mono<String>

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have written some unit test using reactor flux and mono. In flux unit test is working fine. Is not working in mono. Please give me a solution.

```
@Test
public void monoError() {
    Mono<String> monoError = Mono.just("HelloWorld").concatWith(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("error"))).log();
    StepVerifier.create(monoError).expectNext("HellowWorld").expectErrorMessage("error").verify();
}
```

Comment: It says the problem right there in the error

Comment: You try to save a `Flux<String>` in a `Mono<String>`

Comment: You can call single on flux to get mono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet doesn't compile.

Anyways: the "concatWith" operator returns a Flux, so you have to change the variable, the rest works like you probably expected.

Here the working code:

```
@Test
public void monoError() {
  Flux<String> monoError = Mono.just("HelloWorld")
      .concatWith(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("error")))
      .log();          ;
  StepVerifier.create(monoError)
      .expectNext("HelloWorld")
      .expectErrorMessage("error")
      .verify();
}
```